# How to connection Mongo Client with High Availability

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am able to connect to `MongoDB` with high availability using `Mongoose`. Please have a look at my code.

```
function connectMongoose() {
    mongoose.connect(db_url, {
        server: {
            ha: true, // Make sure the high availability checks are on
            haInterval: 5000,
            auto_reconnect: true,
            socketOptions: {
                keepAlive: 1,
                connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
                socketTimeoutMS: 30000,
            }
        },
        replset: {
            ha: true, // Make sure the high availability checks are on
            haInterval: 5000,
            auto_reconnect: true,
            socketOptions: {
                keepAlive: 1,
                connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
                socketTimeoutMS: 30000,
            }
        }
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        if (mongoose.connection.db.serverConfig.s.replset) {
            console.log("Adding replicaSet ha listener...");
            mongoose.connection.db.serverConfig.s.replset.on('ha', function(type, data) {
                console.log('replset ha ' + type);
            })
        }
        if (mongoose.connection.db.serverConfig.s.server) {
            console.log("Adding server ha listener...");
            mongoose.connection.db.serverConfig.s.server.on('ha', function(type, data) {
                console.log('server ha ' + type);
            })
        }
    });
}

connectMongoose();

mongoose.connection.on('connecting', function() {
    console.log('Connecting to MongoDB...');
});
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
    console.log('MongoDB connected!');
});
mongoose.connection.on('open', function() {
    console.log('MongoDB connection opened!');
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('Error in MongoDb connection: ' + err.stack);
    console.log(err);
    mongoose.disconnect();
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function() {
    console.log('MongoDB disconnected!');
    connectMongoose();
});
mongoose.connection.on('reconnected', function() {
    console.log('MongoDB reconnected!');
});
mongoose.connection.on('close', function() {
    console.log('MongoDB closed');
});
```

How can I achieve this by using MongoClient.

Currently I am doing this without high availability checks.

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(db_url, function(err, client) {
    if (err) { return console.dir(err); }
    global.db = client.db(config.mongo.db);
    console.log("Database connection 2 ready ==> Using MongoClient");
});
```

I am doing this because I want to have 2 mongodb connections. With first connection I can query with Schemas. And with second connection I can query collection without schema.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(db_url, {
    ha: true, // Make sure the high availability checks are on
    haInterval: 5000,
    auto_reconnect: true,
    keepAlive: 1,
    connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
    socketTimeoutMS: 30000
});
mongoClient.connect(function(err, client) {....});
```

or with static method in your example:

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(
    db_url, 
    {
        ha: true, // Make sure the high availability checks are on
        haInterval: 5000,
        auto_reconnect: true,
        keepAlive: 1,
        connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
        socketTimeoutMS: 30000
    },
    function(err, client) {....}
);
```

See https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/3.0.0/lib/mongo_client.js for details and more examples.

Comment: How do I listen to the events `connected, disconnected, etc.`?

Comment: You cannot. If you are not using mongoose there are no mongoose events.